# How can I recursively copy files without overwriting existing permissions?

Tags: command-line, permissions

When I copy files from one directory to another, the directory permissions get reset (e.g: from 0755 to 0775), and this causes problems, forcing me to go back and manually reset directory permissions. I'm currently doing `cp -r /source/directory /destination/directory`

I want to copy all of the files and new directories, but not overwrite permissions of existing directories.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To preserve links you may use `cp` ([manpage for cp](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/en/man1/cp.1.html) ) with the `-d` flag, which is equivalent to `--no-dereference --preserve=links`.

To combine this with the `-p` and `-R` flags you can use the archive flag `-a`.

Answer (score 7):

Add -p flag

```
cp -pR /source/dir /dest/dir
```

From `man cp`:

```
-p     same as --preserve=mode,ownership,timestamps
```

Answer (score 2):

My `~/.bashrc` has been modified to contain

```
alias cp='cp -i --preserve=all'
```

This means when I use `cp`, it will also prompt before overwriting (`-i`), and preserve all (i.e. mode, ownership, timestamps; and if possible additional attributes: context, links, xattr).

You could always change it to just `mode` instead of `all` if you like, but I do like having this alias to change the defaults of `cp`.